Dynamic SelectInput choices based on another input's value
i am trying to update a select Input's value based on the choice selected by another select input. if the first's option is selected then immediately the other's value gets update
I am able to see the change working perfectly in the logs but the ui is not getting re-render and the updated value is not getting displayed.
below is the code which i implemented react-admin v4.11.3 , react-hook-form v^7.45.0
Edit.js
        const DEdit = ({ ...props }) => {
        const record = useRecordContext();
        const { control, setValue, watch } = useForm({
            defaultValues:record
        });
        const [openingTime, setOpeningTime] = useState(null);
        const [openingTimeIndex, setOpeningTimeIndex] = useState(null);
        const [closingTime, setClosingTime] = useState(null);
        const [closingTimeIndex, setClosingTimeIndex] = useState(null);
        const [closingTimeChoices, setClosingTimeChoices] = useState([]);
        
        const deliveryTimePref = watch("delivery_time_pref");
        const siteOpeningTime = watch("site_opening_time");


        const openingTimeChoices = React.useMemo(
            () => getTimeInterval(0, false, deliveryTimePref),
            [deliveryTimePref]
        );


        const handleOpeningTimeChange = (value) => {
            const updatedClosingTimeChoices = getTimeInterval(value, true, 
              deliveryTimePref);
            setClosingTimeChoices(updatedClosingTimeChoices);

            const nextIndex = value + 1;
            if (nextIndex < updatedClosingTimeChoices.length) {
            setValue("site_closing_time", nextIndex);
            } else {
            setValue("site_closing_time", 0);
            }
        };

        useEffect(() => {
            setClosingTimeChoices(getTimeInterval(0, true, deliveryTimePref));
        }, [deliveryTimePref]);


        useEffect(() => {
            if (
            data?.customer_order_status !== "0" &&
            DOdSystem() !== "isM"
            ) {
            redirect(`/path/${path[2]}/show`);
            }
            if (data?.mode_of_delivery === "delivered") {
            setOpeningTime(moment(data?.delivery_date_from).format("HH:mm"));
            setClosingTime(moment(data?.delivery_to_date).format("HH:mm"));
            setIndex(
                getTimeInterval(0, false, data?.delivery_time_pref).findIndex(
                (x) => x.name === moment(data?.delivery_date_from).format("HH:mm")
                )
            );
            }
        }, []);

        useEffect(() => {
            if (data && data?.mode_of_delivery === "delivered") {
            const openTimeIndex = getTimeInterval(
                0,
                false,
                data.delivery_time_pref
            ).findIndex(
                (x) =>
                x.name === moment(data.delivery_date_from).format("HH:mm")
            );
            if (openTimeIndex !== -1) {
                setOpeningTimeIndex(openTimeIndex);
                setValue("site_opening_time", openTimeIndex);
                
            }

            const closeTimeIndex = getTimeInterval(
                0,
                false,
                data.delivery_time_pref
            ).findIndex(
                (x) =>
                x.name === moment(data.delivery_to_date).format("HH:mm")
            );
            if (closeTimeIndex !== -1) {
                setClosingTimeIndex(closeTimeIndex);
                setValue("site_closing_time", closeTimeIndex);
                
            }

            console.log('-',openTimeIndex,closeTimeIndex,siteOpeningTime);
            }
        }, [data,getTimeInterval,setValue]);





        const EditToolbar = () => (
            <Toolbar style={{ justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <SaveButton/>
            </Toolbar>
        );



        const transform = (data) => ({
            ...data,
            delivery_date_from:
            openingTime !== null
                ? data?.delivery_date_from.replace(
                    moment(data?.delivery_date_from).utc().format("HH:mm:ss"),
                    moment(openingTime, "HH:m").utc().format("HH:mm:ss")
                )
                : data?.delivery_date_from,
            delivery_to_date:
            closingTime !== null
                ? data?.delivery_to_date.replace(
                    moment(data?.delivery_to_date).utc().format("HH:mm:ss"),
                    moment(closingTime, "HH:m").utc().format("HH:mm:ss")
                )
                : data?.delivery_to_date,
        });

        function isInRange(number, array) {
            return number >= 0 && number < array.length;
        }

        return (
            <Edit
            title="D Edit"
            actions={<EditActions permissions={permissions} />}
            redirect="show"
            mutationMode="pessimistic"
            transform={data?.mode_of_delivery === "delivered" && transform}
            >
            <SimpleForm toolbar={<EditToolbar />}>
                <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>

                {data?.mode_of_delivery === "delivered" && (
                    <FormDataConsumer>
                    {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
                        let deliveryDatesArray = getTimeInterval(0, false, 
                             formData?.delivery_time_pref);

                        return (
                        <Grid container spacing={1}>
                            <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <TextInput disabled source="delivery_time_pref" />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controller
                            name="site_opening_time"
                            control={control}
                            render={({ field }) => (
                                <SelectInput
                                {...field}
                                source="site_opening_time"
                                label="Site opening time"
                                choices={openingTimeChoices}
                                validate={required()}
                                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                                    setOpeningTime(
                                    getTimeInterval(
                                        0,
                                        false,
                                        formData?.delivery_time_pref
                                    )[value].name
                                    );
                                    setIndex(value);
                                    setOpeningTimeIndex(value);
                                    field.onChange(value);
                                    handleOpeningTimeChange(value);
    
        
                                if (isInRange(value+1,deliveryDatesArray)) {
                                    setClosingTimeIndex(value+1);
                                    setClosingTime(
                                    getTimeInterval(
                                        0,
                                        false,
                                        formData?.delivery_time_pref
                                    )[value+1].name
                                    );
        
                                    setValue("site_closing_time", value);
        
                                }else{
                                    setClosingTimeIndex(0);
                                    setClosingTime(
                                    getTimeInterval(
                                        0,
                                        false,
                                        formData?.delivery_time_pref
                                    )[0].name
                                    );
                                    setValue("site_closing_time", value);
                                }
                                }}
                                defaultValue={openingTimeIndex}
                                disabled={formData?.delivery_time_pref === "PM"}
                                />

                            )}
                            />
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={2}>
                            <Controller
                                name="site_closing_time"
                                control={control}
                                render={({ field }) => (
                                <SelectInput
                                    {...field}
                                    source="site_closing_time"
                                    label="Site closing time"
                                    choices={closingTimeChoices}
                                    emptyValue={10}
                                    validate={required()}
                                    onChange={({ target: { value } }) =>{
                                    field.onChange(value);
                                    setClosingTime(
                                        getTimeInterval(
                                        index,
                                        true,
                                        formData?.delivery_time_pref
                                        )[value].name
                                    )
                                    setClosingTimeIndex(value)
                                    }
                                }
                                    defaultValue={closingTimeIndex}
                                    disabled={formData?.delivery_time_pref === "AM"}
                                />
                                )}
                            />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        );
                    }}
                    </FormDataConsumer>
                )}
                </Box>
            </SimpleForm>
            </Edit>
        );
        };

        export default DEdit;

